# How can I wake up my Nexus One using trackball?

Tags: nexus-one, power-on, trackball

I have Nexus One and the power button stopped working. It's a known issue but I'm not in USA and I can't get it fixed since I got it from there. Is there any way that I could wake it up without using the power button and without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what ROM you have, but if you're using a Cyanogen based you can tweak that in the Cyanogen specific settings.

Comment: I have the original Gingerbread by Google

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [AnyUnlock](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.liberty.android.anyunlock&hl=en) from the android market. it is free and lets you set any button be the button to turn the device on. It has been tested exclusively for the Nexus One.

Actually, I read further in the description, the trackball can no longer be used as of gingerbread.